# Webpack Angular 2 less-loader config

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, less

I am trying to use less-loader to compile the .less files associated with my Angular 2 .ts components and for the life of me I can't get it to work properly.

```
module.exports = {

  entry: './client/main.ts',
  output: {
  path: './dist',
  filename: 'app.bundle.js'
 },
  module: {
  loaders: [
           {test: /\.ts$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'ts'},
            {test: /\.html$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'raw'},
            {test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'css-loader'},
            {test: /\.less$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'raw!less-loader'}
            ]
     },

     resolve: {
     extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts', '.html', '.css', '.less']
     },
     plugins: [
     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
     template: './client/index.html'
     }),
     new webpack.DefinePlugin({
     app: {
     environment: JSON.stringify(process.env.APP_ENVIRONMENT || 
     'development')
  }
```

I have installed 'less-loader' via npm. I load my styles in my components as follows
    import {Component} from "@angular/core";

```
@Component({
    selector:'welcome',
    template: require('./welcome.component.html'),
    styleUrls: require('./welcome.less')
 })
 export class WelcomeComponent{}
```

My folder structure is

```
-webpack.config.js
    -client/
        -welcome/
            welcome.component.ts
            welcome.less
```

Here is the full error

```
app.bundle.js:13838 Uncaught TypeError: stylesheet.styles.map is not a 
function
    at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeStylesheet 
(http://localhost:3000/app.bundle.js:13838:46)
    at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeLoadedTemplate 
(http://localhost:3000/app.bundle.js:13778:46)
    at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplateSync 
(http://localhost:3000/app.bundle.js:13763:24)
    at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeDirective 
(http://localhost:3000/app.bundle.js:13739:46)
    at RuntimeCompiler._createCompiledTemplate 
(http://localhost:3000/app.bundle.js:17139:211)
    at http://localhost:3000/app.bundle.js:17077:44
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at http://localhost:3000/app.bundle.js:17075:51
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents 
(http://localhost:3000/app.bundle.js:17074:46)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used the following setup

Install less and less-loader:

```
npm install --save-dev less
npm install --save-dev less-loader
```

In your webpack config (i.e. "webpack.common.js"), first require this plugin:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
```

And add these rules. The first one handles less files outside the app, the second handles less files inside the app:

```
{
    test: /\.less$/,
    exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: 'css-loader!less-loader' })
},
{
    test: /\.less$/,
    include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
    loader: 'raw-loader!less-loader'
},...
```

In your main app (i.e. "app.component.ts"), import your main less file.

```
import '../../assets/css/main.less';
```

Inside a component (i.e. "view.component.ts"):

```
@Component({
    ...
    styleUrls: ['./../styles/view.component.less']
})
```

Inside the component less file (i.e. "view.component.less"):

```
// import from node modules
@import "~bootstrap/less/variables.less";
@import "~bootstrap/less/mixins.less";
// import custom less files
@import "../../assets/css/variables.less";
```